# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have a TableCell like this:

```
<asp:TableCell CssClass="plusTd button" ID="plusCell">
                        </asp:TableCell>
```

I added a property to it like this:

```
plusCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "/Add.aspx");
```

when I click on that cell, i got this error on the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /
```

what am i missing please?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect on click event, use this

```
plusCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.location='/Add.aspx'");
```